# cpio basic extract command, 'tar xzvf' equivalent?

Tags: cpio

I've received a Unix software distribution as a compressed cpio file.  What's the best command to extract the files?

Comment: When you did `man cpio` what did you see?

Comment: I see: -i -o -p -t -B -c -C -f -F -H -M -n -v -V -W -b -r -s -S -E -A -O -l -0 -a -I -L -R -d -m -u -? --extract --create --pass-through --list --block-size= --io-size= --force-local --nonmatching --file= --format= --message= --numeric-uid-gid --quiet --rsh-command= --verbose --dot --warning= --swap --rename --swap-bytes --swap-halfwords --to-stdout --pattern-file= --only-verify-crc --append --link --absolute-filenames --no-absolute-filenames --null --reset-access-time --dereference --owner= --make-directories --preserve-modification-time --no-preserve-owner --sparse --unconditional

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
gzip -cd foo.cpio.gz | cpio -idmv
```

- i : extract (input)
- d : create directories
- m : preserve mtime
- v : verbose

Answer (score 7):

```
mkdir archive
cd archive
zcat ../archive.cpio.gz | cpio -idmv --no-absolute-filenames
```

While this is an old question, it shows up high on Google, so I thought I might update it.  I agree with the accepted answer in general, but you should add "--no-absolute-filenames" unless you are intending to overwrite important system files on your machine.  Also, personally, I prefer "zcat" over "gzip -cd" or "gunzip -c".

Finally, note that you need to run cpio as root (e.g. sudo) if you are extracting a root filesystem that contains device nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to extract the archived contents of /etc/httpd/ to the current directory, creating subdirectories ./etc/httpd/

```
mkdir restored-etc-httpd
cd restored-etc-httpd    
zcat archive.cpio.gz | cpio -idmv --no-absolute-filenames "*etc/httpd/*"
```

The accepted answer and Matt's were both helpful to me but I was stumped for a while because of three details:

1. The matching pattern needs to be quoted to work as a pattern :P
2. The option `--no-absolute-filenames` must *precede* the pattern on the command line
3. Since that option removes the leading `/` from filenames, the matching pattern must also omit the leading `/`

Answer (score -1):

This Wikipedia page on [**`cpio`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) has some good notes.
For more details, refer to the [`cpio` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/html_mono/cpio.html).

A link from the same Wikipedia page [discusses comparison with `tar` archives](http://rightsock.com/~kjw/Ramblings/tar_v_cpio.html).
And, here is an example of [using `cpio` with the `tar` format](http://smartgeeks.co.cc/wp/tag/cpio/).